# Why the port type of this module default to 'var'?

Tags: fpga, system-verilog

In "IEEE Std 1800-2012 SystemVerilog", p. 668, I find this:

```
module mh11(output integer x); // output var integer x
```

I wonder why it is default to 'var' but not 'net'? Which rule defines it, or itself just is the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is on the previous page

> **If the port kind is omitted**: — **For output ports**, the default port kind depends on how the data type
>   is specified: 
>     — If the data type is omitted or declared with the
>   implicit_data_type syntax, the port kind shall default to a net of
>   default net type. 
>     — If the data type is **declared with the explicit
>   data_type syntax**, the port kind shall default to **variable**.

These implicit rules are ridiculously complex in order to save a few keystrokes. You are much safer to be explicit.